# Component linking tag are not generating in the page

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We have set up tridion to publish to two servers-publishing target set to two locations.

- License is installed in both the servers
- All config and lib files are in place.

When we tried to publish to the servers using second environment-test CME server it is publishing and Component linking tag are generating in the page.
When published from first envirnment-dev CME server Component linking tag are not generating in the page. the below error is logged

```
 WARN  Admin - WAI: Could not find a presentation for SiteIdentifier[Protocol=http; Domain=*.*.*.*; Port=****; Path=/HTTPUpload.aspx]
2012-12-18 05:19:28,351 ERROR UserManager - No Data Access Object for Personalization
com.tridion.broker.StorageException: No Data Access Object for Personalization
    at com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory.getDAOForTypeMapping(FSDAOFactory.java:177) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getOriginalDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:450) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:271) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDefaultDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:178) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.user.UserManager.checkUser(UserManager.java:56) ~[cd_wai.jar:na]
```

Also event viewer is showing

```
Can't initialize application heartbeat monitoring: 0x80040154
Source:
SetupThreadHeartbeat
```

- what are the config needed  in CME server for dynamic linking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CME does not need any configuration for Dynamic Linking, as that is something you configure and use on the Presentation side (your web/application server).

The error message you post indicate that your WAI (Profiling and personalization) setup is incorrect, and maybe more. I suggest you start with a basic setup and make that work, that should have linking working, before you add things like WAI which you might not even need.

The error message about the heartbeat is indicating an issue with the monitoring configuration, which again indicates that you seem to have a lot of configuration issues.Perhaps its best to start from the beginning again and follow the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_FFBC376AF96D4EBBB0E346C18A711187) (login required) from step to step in how to setup your Content Delivery server.

*Another option always is to call SDl Tridion Professional Services and hire a Infrasturcture Consultant to setup your environment.*

Comment: Thank you. I was suspecting the installation/config issue of the environment.